# Xamarin iOS Table View Cells Intersecting Search Bar

Tags: ios, xamarin, tableview, searchbar

I'm writing an iOS app using Xamarin and am having a problem with a table view and search bar - when the search bar has been clicked and text entered, the search results view controller doesn't work properly - the cells, when scrolled, intersect the search bar.

For clarity, I've recorded the problem:

[YouTube - iOS Problem](https://youtu.be/0ij9H6z9hNg)

So far, I've worked-out that the problem isn't related to the number of sections, the section header, or the table header. Completely out of ideas now, though...

The following can be used as an example, as the same problem appears there:

[GitHub - TableSearch](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/ios8/TableSearch)

In this example, adding the following line of code to the end of the 'ViewDidLoad ()' method within the 'MainTableViewController.cs' file will make the problem more obvious:

searchController.SearchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal;

EDIT

Looking at the image below, I ideally need to remove or shrink the top region (what seems to be a space for the iOS navigation bar):

[image: Annotated]

Comment: Are you able to post any of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at the sample from Xamarin [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/ios8/TableSearch) which has the same layout you are using, just to compare how you set up the search bar.

**EDIT**
I now see what you mean, I think this is a bug in iOS as the background color is transparent on the search bar and you would never want that. 
I just added another view to cover up the status bar and set the background color to white:

```
        searchController.SearchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal;

        searchController.SearchBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        var frame = searchController.SearchBar.Frame;
        frame.Height = searchController.SearchBar.Frame.Height + 22; 
        frame.Y = searchController.SearchBar.Frame.Y - 22;
        var bckGRound = new UIView (frame);
        bckGRound.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        searchController.SearchBar.InsertSubview (bckGRound, 0);
```

**UPDATE**
I realised that for your scenario you can't just add a view to cover this up so i was looking into adding blurring to searchbar like so:

```
        var frame = searchController.SearchBar.Frame;
        frame.Height = searchController.SearchBar.Frame.Height + 44; 
        frame.Y = searchController.SearchBar.Frame.Y - 22;

        var blurryBackGround = new UIView (frame);
        if (!UIAccessibility.IsReduceTransparencyEnabled) 
        {
            blurryBackGround.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            var blureffect = UIBlurEffect.FromStyle (UIBlurEffectStyle.Light);
            var blureffectview = new UIVisualEffectView (blureffect);
            blureffectview.Frame = frame;
            blurryBackGround.AddSubview (blureffectview);
        }
        else
        {
            blurryBackGround.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
        }
        searchController.SearchBar.InsertSubview (blurryBackGround, 0);
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

If your background doesnt move with the table then you might be able to get away with just cropping the background image section that the search bar covers then set the backgroundimage for the search bar with this code:

```
        searchController.SearchBar.SetBackgroundImage (new UIImage ("image.jpg"), UIBarPosition.TopAttached, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

Comment: I've taken a look at the code, and it seems that it has the same problem as this - when you do a search, and scroll-up, the results go up and behind the search bar; it becomes more noticeable when you change the 'SearchBarStyle' property to 'UISearchBarStyle.Minimal'. This sample does however seem to show that the odd gap that the results go into (what I thought might have been a header view), seems to be a space for the iOS navigation bar...

Comment: I really need to keep the background of the search bar region transparent... I could change the background colour of the search bar (where you type) to white, though, which would help to alleviate the problem - how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Not ideal because of the nature of the background, but it is a definite improvement. If no other solutions are found, I'll most likely use this; thank you for giving me the option.

Comment: My last update (update 2) might work to keep the background where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

That is the UISearchController's default behavior. You can change the background color so that the rows don't appear behind the searchBar but that doesn't appear to be the behavior you want. Another option is to implement the UISearchBar on your ViewController which is what I have and it does scroll with the rows which is the behavior you are looking for. Hope this helps.

See: https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/SearchDemo/SearchDemo

Comment: I think our projects differ - I'm using a view controller for the search display controller, and that is probably where the navigation bar is coming from - how do I programmatically set the 'TopBar' to 'None' (like within a storyboard) for a view controller? I can't set the navigation bar to hidden as the 'NavigationController' for the view controller returns 'null'.

Comment: @Luke How are you pushing/loading your search view controller? I think what you want is the NavigationBarHidden property of the NavigationController.

Comment: 'UIViewController searchResultsViewController = new UIViewController();' and 'searchDisplayController = new UISearchDisplayController(tblTaskSearch, searchResultsViewController);' - As it stands, I can't set the 'NavigationBarHidden' property as the 'NavigationController' property returns 'null'.